# How do I attach a Google Doc to a Yahoo e-mail

Tags: google-docs, yahoo-mail

I need to attach a Google Doc to a Yahoo e-mail.  When I click on the attachment icon, it takes me to Google drive, but it won't attach the file.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send a copy of the actual file, then you need to download it (presumably to a format that some other desktop software can read, eg Excel, Word, Powerpoint etc), and then attach the locally-downloaded file.

An alternative is to get a link to the file, and just paste that link into your email.  If you do this, then the email recipient will need to have a Google account, but they will see the original file not your downloaded copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous poster said, one option is to download the file from Google Drive, then attach it to the email.

Or, if you have Google Drive installed on your computer, you can attach the file directly from there. That's what I usually do, it simplifies things.